# Include YAML file in RMarkdown document

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, knitr

I have an RMarkdown document that includes an example YAML file, currently in the form:

````
```{yaml}
name: r40_tidyverse
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults
dependencies:
  - r-base=4.0
  - r-tidyverse
```
````

This renders (knits) into HTML with nice YAML syntax highlighting.

**Knitted Result**
[image: rendered YAML code]

Instead of the above, I would like to include it as an external YAML file, say at `envs/r40_tidyverse.yaml`. I have tried using

````
```{yaml child="envs/r40_tidyverse.yaml"}
```
````

While this correctly loads the file, the resulting HTML is merely a `<p></p>` element with the contents of the file located within it.

**Knitted Result**
[image: not-so-rendered YAML file]

This is not desirable.

**How can one load an external YAML file into an RMarkdown document and achieve syntax highlighting similar to when including a YAML code chunk directly?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest way is that you read the external file in an inline R expression, e.g.,

````
```yaml
`r xfun::file_string('envs/r40_tidyverse.yaml')`
```
````

Note that you should not use  ```` ```{yaml} ```` (i.e., do not add `{}` to `yaml`), because that would change its meaning to **knitr**:

- With curly braces, it means a code chunk, and a **knitr** language engine needs to evaluate the code chunk (but there is not a `yaml` engine yet, and your first example worked just by chance).
- Without curly braces, it means a normal code block, which will not be processed by **knitr**.

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. BTW, thanks for all the amazing work!